# Trying to sum from a jquery selector and update an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, selector

I need to sum some text elements and update an input text, following is the far I could go:

This would be a correct example. I want to sum the text from within the `<span>` if the the `<tr>` contains the class ui-state-error

HTML

```
  <table>
<tr id="rp-10-1-1" class="ui-state-error" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
    <td><span id="pr-10-1-1">100</span><td>
  </tr>  
<tr id="rp-10-1-2" class="ui-state-highlight" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
  <td><span id="pr-10-1-2">200</span><td>
</tr>  
<tr id="rp-10-1-3" class="ui-state-error" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
  <td><span id="pr-10-1-3">300</span><td>
</tr>  
</tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="sumhere">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
        $( 'tr[id^="rp-"]' ).click(
          function() {

        $('tr[id^="rp-"]').each(function(data, val) {

            var rps = $(this).attr("id").split("-");


              if ($("#pr-" + rps[1] + '-' + rps[2] + '-' + rps[3]).hasClass("ui-state-error")) {
                console.log($("#pr-" + rps[1] + "-" + rps[2] + "-" + rps[3]).text());
              }
        });
         }
        );
```

Comment: `tr` direct child sould be a `td` not a span.

Comment: I made a wrong example, sorry: I'm updating it right now.

Comment: The console.log is referencing an element with id starting with `pr` ... should that be `rp` ?  Also, please explain what your intention is with inspecting the span id, and what text you're trying to sum.  It's really not clear why you are splitting the id.

Comment: Sorry to make you read a wron example, apologizes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr` would `td` are not recognized as a valid html. If you wish to extract just the total of the `span` elements, you may do the following :

```
var total = 0;
$('span[id^=hp]').each(function() // selects span starting with id=hp
{
  total += parseInt($(this).text());
});

$("#sumhere").val(total);
```

Based on your updated HTML :

```
var total = 0;
$('tr[id^=rp-10-1] span').each(function() // selects span withing the tr element starting with id=rp-10-1
{
  if(!isNaN(parseInt($(this).text()))) // condition for safety check while converting text to interger.
   total += parseInt($(this).text());
});

$("#sumhere").val(total);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/7nhx26a2/3/

Comment: be careful using this solution without validating $(this).text().

Comment: @devlincarnate: That's for the opinion. Added safe conversion condition.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zzaj1jye/

HTML:

```
<tr id="rp-10-1-1">
  <span id="hp-10-1-1" class="ui-state-error">10</span>
  <span id="hp-10-1-2" class="ui-state-error">20</span>
  <span id="hp-10-1-3" class="ui-state-error">30</span>
</tr>

<input type="text" id="sumhere">
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

  var total = 0;
  $('span').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('ui-state-error') ) {
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
    }
  });

   $("#sumhere").val(total);

});
```

Comment: You can simply do $('span.ui-state-error ') for your each selector

Comment: I know. But he use `hasClass` inside the question. Maybe he wants to do something with it. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't matter. $('span.ui-state-error ') would only select span with class .ui-state-error '

Comment: Yes, I need to use hasClass as there are other elements which contains this class and aren't part of the sum. Thank you!